# sudo followed by another command in ssh heredoc not working

Tags: ssh, bash, sudo, heredoc

This is my script:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "I'm local"

ssh -t -t remote.server << 'EOF'
    sudo echo "I'm remote and sudo"
    echo "I'm remote but not sudo"
    exit
EOF
```

This simply doesn't work, maybe because the line `echo "I'm not sudo"` is supplied as a password.

How can I make it work, without:

- feeding the password directly to the script
- enabling password-less sudo, or
- making everything sudo?

Or, perhaps my approach is completely wrong or unusual for this purpose?

Comment: Have you found the solution other than my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion the only way is to split into two separate ssh commands:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "I'm local"

ssh -t remote.server "sudo echo \"I'm remote and sudo\""
ssh -t remote.server "echo \"I'm remote but not sudo\""
```

The redirection which you use, will always redirect whole block to the command and will not wait for any subcommand success (or fail).